# Why cast as timestamp give out two different result

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have a hive table with two rows like this:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default> select * from t2;
+-----+--------+
| id  | value  |
+-----+--------+
| 10  | 100    |
| 11  | 101    |
+-----+--------+
2 rows selected (1.116 seconds)
```

but when I issue a query :

```
select cast(1 as timestamp) from t2;
```

it gives out unconsistent result, can anyone tell me the reason ?

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default> select cast(1 as timestamp) from t2;
+--------------------------+
|           _c0            |
+--------------------------+
| 1970-01-01 07:00:00.001  |
| 1970-01-01 07:00:00.001  |
+--------------------------+
2 rows selected (0.913 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default> select cast(1 as timestamp) from t2;
+--------------------------+
|           _c0            |
+--------------------------+
| 1970-01-01 08:00:00.001  |
| 1970-01-01 07:00:00.001  |
+--------------------------+
2 rows selected (1.637 seconds)
```

Comment: `case` or `cast`?

Comment: it's cast, convert int to timestamp

Comment: BTW, why are you doing it in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem, which Hive version are you  using? Hive had a bug with timestamp and bigint (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3454), but it doesn't explain your problem. For example Hive 0.14 gives different results for

```
SELECT (cast 1 as timestamp), cast(cast(1 as double) as timestamp) from my_table limit 5;
```